# Why can't I call any page created in node express?

Tags: node.js, express, pugjs

I'm using the ExpressJS web framework for NodeJS.

I don't know why to have 404 error messages when creating a new page and call it.

My directory structure:

```
| my-application
    | src
        | routes
            | index.js
            | single.js
        | views
            | index.pug
            | single.pug
        | ...
```

Code `single.js` in `routes` folder:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET single page. */
router.get('/single', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('single', { title: 'Blog single' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Code in `app.js`:

```
// ...
var index = require('./src/routes/index');
var single = require('./src/routes/single');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/single', single);
// ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: Don't post code as images... copy it hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
app.use('/single', single);
```

along with the `single` router creates a route handler for `/single/single`, not for just `/single`.  It registers a router to handle all `/single` routes and then that router itself registers `/single` creating the handler for `/single/single`.

You can either change the `router.get()` to handle just `/` instead of `/single`. or you can change the `app.use()` to not have a path.  You probably want to change the router.